# How can I call a specific function based on url in python web frameworks?

Tags: python, flask, eve

I have developed a python application which takes in post variables and inserts data into postgresql. 
Now I want to call specific function when we call a url.

For example

```
if  I do
  curl -i http://127.0.0.1:5000/abc/cde
  it should call 
   def aaa()
  if curl -i http://127.0.0.1:5000/pqr/xyz
  it should call 
  def bbb()
```

is there a way to achieve that in python flask web frameworks ?

Comment: Of course you can do that, routing to functions based on URLs is the fundamental feature of web frameworks. The Flask tutorial shows you exactly how to do it.

Comment: It is not working with python-eve. I did used app.route()

Answer (score 2):

This is the one of the main features of a web framework. The most minimal example in [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/) would be:

```
# my_app.py

from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/abc/cde')
def aaa():
    return 'Hello, this is aaa'

@app.route('/pqr/xyz')
def bbb():
    return 'Hello, this is bbb'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

You can then run this:

> $ python my_app.py

Like any Python script. I suggest you have a look at [Flask's Quickstart](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#quickstart) page as a starting point.

Comment: I am aware of this but with python-eve, it is not returning what I require. This is not working with python-eve

Comment: Then why didn't you ask about that?